# MySQL 8.0.34 - managing persistent connection memory usage on AWS RDS from Backend Systems

Tags: mysql, connection, amazon-rds

**01.26.2024 Update Below**
**01.25.2024 Update Below**
**01.24.2024 Update Below**

Server Details Here: [Server Details](https://justpaste.it/fw26r)

We have an issue where some old (bad) legacy code of our backend system is keeping MySQL connections open for days and using them for tons of different things, which is eating the freeable memory of our system.

Is there any way to control the amount of memory a connection is allowed to "eat" if it's a long-term reused connection (some of them hold 200MB+ each)? Is there a way to have a connection release its memory hold without severing the connection?

Trying to find a solution while the backend team addresses writing better connection management code (they're not supposed to hold connections open indefinitely).

Here's a picture of the connection RAM. It's NUTS.

[image: RAM usage of our Read Replica]

A core part of this issue is I can't find 100% accurate and definitive information on exactly what parameters define the memory limit of a connection. One site says one grouping, and another has ... another. One site says @@tmp_table_size is connection based, and another says it's "global". I can't believe how much conflicting information is out there... so right now I can't even figure out what parameters define the max memory usage of a connection. Any confirmed details on this would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the values of the parameters I've been told control the memory limits of each connection.

```
@@max_allowed_packet: 64MB
@@sort_buffer_size: 3.81MB
@@read_buffer_size: 256KB
@@read_rnd_buffer_size: 512KB
@@join_buffer_size: 256KB
@@net_buffer_length: 16KB
@@tmp_table_size: 16777216 (107.50MB)
@@max_heap_table_size: 16777216 (16MB)
```

What's more confusing is here's a more recent snapshot showing threads in excess of 300MB nearing 400MB. How is this even possible?

[image: 2nd capture]

Here's another shot showing sys.processlist.

[image: sys.processlist]

I honestly don't know how to dig into this to understand what's going on...

Here's a snapshot of a thread that's using 132MB. Note this is after we rebooted the server so it's not near the 400MB level. Notice anything strange?

[image]

Here's the SQL I use to get the memory details for the threads and processes:

```
  -- Memory used by the processes.
SELECT
    th.THREAD_ID,
    th.PROCESSLIST_ID,
    th.PROCESSLIST_USER,
    th.PROCESSLIST_HOST,
    th.PROCESSLIST_DB,
    th.PROCESSLIST_COMMAND,
    th.PROCESSLIST_TIME,
    ev.EVENT_NAME,
    FORMAT_BYTES(ev.CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED)
FROM
  performance_schema.threads th
  JOIN performance_schema.memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name ev
  ON th.THREAD_ID = ev.THREAD_ID
WHERE
  ev.EVENT_NAME LIKE 'memory/%' and th.PROCESSLIST_USER IS NOT NULL AND th.PROCESSLIST_USER <> 'rdsrepladmin' AND th.PROCESSLIST_USER <> 'empoweradmin43'
ORDER BY
ev.CURRENT_NUMBER_OF_BYTES_USED DESC, th.PROCESSLIST_TIME DESC;
```

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for getting Sleep'ing processes better managed.

Comment: @WilsonHauck actually the first question is what parameters define the max use for a connection? I've spent hours online researching it and there's a lack of consistency. Half of the SQL memory calculators I've used are flat out wrong... is there any place you know of that is 100% correct with 8.0.34 memory use parameters for each connection?

Comment: Floobinator    Try   use information_schema;  then   SELECT * from processlist; should serve you everything MySQL knows about each process. not connection but process as shown in htop, first column if you are trying to match the use of RAM.  View profile and get in touch, please.   See dba.stackexchange.com Question 335130 my comment that starts 'When htop shows Sleeping............. for hanging on Sleep'ing processes.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Updated the above with new information and a screenshot from your recommendation.

Comment: What you posted is not from information_schema; SELECT * from processlist; match ProcessID to SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; for it to make any sense, please.

Comment: @WilsonHauck apologies; I don't understand. SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST is a list of 35 entries with ID, user, host, etc. There doesn't appear to be any pertinent information in it. I'm not sure how to join that with the sys.processlist...?

Comment: Can you from MySQL command prompt, USE information_schema;  to set your working database?  Then SELECT * FROM processlist;  The SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; should show you active queries in the INFO column that may be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks @WilsonHauck - I understand now. I already did that, but the information doesn't tell me why connections are taking upwards of 400MB when based on the information above it should be impossible. As I mentioned, I find it virtually impossible to tell why a connection is taking the RAM it is - conflicting documentation and other factors. Also, is there any way to get a list of the session variables of a specific connection? I wonder if there's some rogue session variables that are being set and forgot... but hundreds of MB would be a lot.

Comment: @WilsonHauck just added another image at the bottom showing the memory breakdown of a specific thread.

Comment: It appears Stored Procedures are being used frequently.  If you could post the Additional information requested in my first comment, we might find a suggestion or two to avoid burning 400MB for a thread.  It will take time to analyze your data, usually less than two business days.

Comment: @WilsonHauck details posted above. One thing came to mind. Is is possible connections are abusing session variables? What's the limit of the max size allowed of session variables per connection? From what I can tell, it's impossible to determine the session variable use of another connection/thread... is this correct? Please let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Comment: If you allow root login from a common user, there is no telling what they can do with SESSION VARIABLES.  Just a word of warning.  You are correct, visibility of connection variables of another is not possible.  Analysis is in process.

Comment: What is your A) AWS RDS instance type? B) Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?

Comment: @WilsonHauck db.m6gd.large. 8GB and 2vCPU. We never have CPU problems, and the 8GB based on all statistics is fine for our current system; we just can't figure out why memory/sql/sp_head::main_mem_root is shooting up past 350MB over a period of hours.

Comment: Floobinator  A) What approximate date did you START using AWS RDS version 8.0.34?  B) Your SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; report indicated about 65 'not started' transactions when the report was generated.  C) The same report indicates only 3 write threads when SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; reports 4 write threads.  D) What are you using to get the Threads report showing 400 MB in use?

Comment: Floobinator, What is your storage technology, HDD - SSD or NVME?

Comment: @WilsonHauck our db.m6gd.large instance uses general purpose SSD (gp3). We've been using 8.0.34 since it came out because it had a bug fix in it that affected our code. I can confirm all the memory is in memory/sql/sp_head::main_mem_root. I've updated the above task with the query I use to get the memory for the processes. Note the biggest issue is with our read-replica, but because it's got the most connections.

Comment: Floobinator, If you would add th.processlist_info  to the select list, you may see the QUERY that caused the use of 400MB.  Please let me know if that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second = RPS or RPhr

Suggestions to consider for AWS RDS Parameters Group,

Static variables (requires stop/start of instance),

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=2  # from 8 until you have more cores - if ever
innodb_open_files=40000  # from 4000 to reduce opened_tables RPhr of 18,127
table_open_cache_instances=2  # from 8 you only have 2 cores
```

Dynamic variables,
temptable_max_mmap=268435456  # from 1G since you only have 8G available
temptable_max_ram=268435456  # from 1G since you only have 8G available
table_open_cache=40000  # from 4000 to reduce match innodb_open_files

Observation,
threads_connected is showing 60 in show global status results.
This is a symptom that Java code to connect, process, close is not
closing the connection and leaving resources in use when the processing is done.
Suggest search for "java mysql connect process close tutorial" and review more than one article to release resources.

There are many more opportunities to adjust Global Variables for performance improvement.

Comment: First, I want to extend my personal thanks to @WilsonHauck for going above and beyond. We did a Skype call and it was very apparent any backend system that keeps a connection open and reuses it for hours or days will bloat the memory (almost like a memory leak), which means it's the responsibility of the BE team to ensure they use proper connection pooling. He also helped in many areas, including the above. Thanks again, Wilson! Our BE team has been chained to their desks :)

Comment: @Floobinator I look forward to hearing from you again in the next few months.